# Progress bar isn't visible when put together with webview

Tags: android, webview, progress-bar

In the `LinearLayout` there is a `WebView` and `ProgressBar` element.

The `WebView` is full screen.

And I try to show the `ProgressBar` when `WebView` is loading something.

But seems `ProgressBar` is covered by `WebView` and thus not visible.

And if I set `WebView` to be invisible ,I can see that `ProgressBar`.

So how can I show the `ProgressBar` on top of the  `WebView`?

Answer (score 5):

Try using a [RelativeLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html) rather than a LinearLayout. Have the WebView as the first child and the ProgressBar as the second, this will place the ProgressBar over the top of the WebView.

Comment: By `top` I mean I want the ProgressBar to have a z-index on top of the webview.

Comment: Yes, the order views are added to a RelativeLayout defines their z-ordering.

Comment: In LinearLayout,if I put the ProgressBar above WebView, `findViewById` won't find the Webview, do you know the reason?

Comment: Is there difference when writing `<WebView />` and `<WebView ...></WebView>`?

Comment: Nope <WebView /> is just shorthand for <WebView ...></WebView>, normally used for views that can't have any children.

Answer (score 2):

You should use a RelativeLayout to do this. It will be something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#1F286D" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBar1"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use android:translationZ attribute in ProgressBar:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:translationZ="2dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

and Use  [RelativeLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.html)

[More information](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524552/android-5-0-progressbar-cannot-be-displayed-over-a-button?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Answer (score 0):

Better way + the progressBar will stay on your screen even when you scroll through the WebView: put the progressbar inside FrameLayout and below WebView...

```
<RelativeLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
       />

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="150dp">

           <ProgressBar
               <!-- your progress bar here-->
             />

      </FrameLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```