# Android 5.0 - ProgressBar cannot be displayed over a Button

Tags: android, android-button, android-progressbar, android-5.0-lollipop

I think the title is pretty explicit about my problem... So here is my layout :

```
            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_action"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Login" />

                <ProgressBar
                    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
                    android:layout_width="50dp"
                    android:layout_height="50dp"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

            </RelativeLayout>
```

On android SDKs < 21, no problem, the ProgressBar is correctly displayed over the Button and centered in the Button. But on Android 5.0, the ProgressBar is displayed **behind** the Button.

So you can see it's correctly positionned it when you activate the option "Show layout bounds" in Developer Options settings, but you can't see anything on the screen without that option.

Would anybody know how to fix this? I guess it's a matter of **elevation** recently introduced, but I really don't know how to take care of it.
For the record, I'm using the recently released Theme.AppCompat style from the support.v7.

**EDIT:**

I also tried to apply `setElevation(0)` and `setTranslationY(0)` to the Button programmatically but it didn't change anything. So I wonder if it has to deal with the elevation.

Comment: Is there any reason why you don't use `FrameLayout`?

Comment: No, not really. Just a matter of habit I guess. Could it change anything?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can add the `android:translationZ` attribute to the `ProgressBar`:

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:translationZ="2dp"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer wpiwonski, but nope, changed nothing

Comment: It's weird. I've checked the code on emulator and ProgressBar is over the Button now. 1 dp was not enough, but 2 dp moved ProgressBar to the front.

Comment: My mistake, I tried to set the Button's translationZ to 0 instead of increasing the ProgressBar's. It works indeed, thanks!

Comment: Note that its API 21+

Comment: I can confirm this worked on a 5.1.1 device. Code can be seen [here](https://github.com/voghDev/ProgressButtonView/blob/master/ProgressButtonView/src/main/res/layout/view_progress_button.xml)

Comment: Using the translationZ attribute worked for me. However, I also had to modify the ProgressBar code above by adding style="@android:style/Widget.ProgressBar.Small".

Comment: @ArpitPatel You shouldn't face that behavior on 21-

Comment: Not working on 28 9.0, only working solution is to set         android:stateListAnimator="@null"
in Button

Comment: Tested on API 30, "2dp" didn't work for me but "4dp" did!

Answer (score 13):

Same issue here, my simple "hack" was too wrap the Button into another FrameLayout.
This way I don't care about the api version and other elevation issue ;)

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button_action"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Login" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <ProgressBar
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 7):

Same question being asked here, with a better explanation of the issue:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27216368/235910

To quote @CommonsWare:

> The problem appears Android 5.0's `elevation` property. Apparently,
>   the `RelativeLayout` Z-axis ordering is tied into `elevation`. If both
>   widgets have the same `elevation`, the `RelativeLayout` will determine
>   the Z-axis order -- you can see that if you were to switch your layout
>   to be both `Button` widgets, for example. However, if one widget
>   (`Button`) has an `elevation`, and another widget (`ImageView`) does
>   not, the `elevation` will take precedence.
>
> You can remove the `Button` `elevation` via
>   `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` or by [defining your own custom
>   animator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27112143/115145). Or, you can add some `elevation` to your `ImageView` to
>   get it to be higher on the Z axis than is the `Button`.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to set android:translationZ more than 2dp. Your view/widget will disappear when you press the button. I explained the reason [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27216080/how-to-bring-imageview-in-front-of-button-in-android-5/27216368#28719568).

```
<!-- Elevation when button is pressed -->
<dimen name="button_elevation_material">1dp</dimen>
<!-- Z translation to apply when button is pressed -->
<dimen name="button_pressed_z_material">2dp</dimen>
```

Button have these two values and defined in the [framework](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/dimens_material.xml).

Answer (score 0):

If you add 'androidx.core:core' to your build.gradle, you can use this code for API < 21:

```
ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(viewToElevate, 5);
```

Answer (score 0):

By default, if you want to show a view on top of a Button, it should have an elevation of at least 2dp.

This is caused by the fact that the elevation of a button is governed by their stateListAnimator. So long as it has one, setting the elevation to the button itself doesn't do anything. The stateListAnimator of `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button` has a default elevation of `@dimen/mtrl_btn_elevation` (2dp), so that's the elevation you have to take into account.

Doing `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` will also work, but that will get rid of any shadow effects at the button.