# How to bring ImageView in front of Button in android 5?

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

In android versions previous to lolipop, the following code works and an image is in front of the button. But in android 5 the imageview is put behind the button.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="210sp"
    android:layout_height="210sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:drawablePadding="10dip"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal" />


<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/torch"
    android:src="?attr/imageview" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Are these inside a `RelativeLayout`?

Comment: @CommonsWare yes they are inside

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The problem appears Android 5.0's `elevation` property. Apparently, the `RelativeLayout` Z-axis ordering is tied into `elevation`. If both widgets have the same `elevation`, the `RelativeLayout` will determine the Z-axis order -- you can see that if you were to switch your layout to be both `Button` widgets, for example. However, if one widget (`Button`) has an `elevation`, and another widget (`ImageView`) does not, the `elevation` will take precedence.

You can remove the `Button` `elevation` via `android:stateListAnimator="@null"` or by [defining your own custom animator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27112143/115145). Or, you can add some `elevation` to your `ImageView` to get it to be higher on the Z axis than is the `Button`.

Comment: just to clarify, some widgets have a pre-set elevation value that overrides the default ordering?

Comment: @LambergaR: I'd phrase it more as: some widgets have aspects that affect their elevation, such as the `stateListAnimator` that is set up by default for a `Button`.

Comment: "android:stateListAnimator="@null" this requires API level 21 and higher but my minsdkversion is 19

Comment: finally i can bring view in front of Button

Comment: Finally, setting android:stateListAnimator="@null" is only solution that works on 28 9.0

Answer (score 3):

Button elevation and translationZ values are defined in framework as below:

```
<!-- Elevation when button is pressed -->
<dimen name="button_elevation_material">1dp</dimen>
<!-- Z translation to apply when button is pressed -->
<dimen name="button_pressed_z_material">2dp</dimen>
```

[Source](http://androidxref.com/5.0.0_r2/xref/frameworks/base/core/res/res/values/dimens_material.xml)

Like CommonsWare explained, set the translationZ of ImageView higher than Button value will give the result as expected.