# Android ConstraintLayout - Put one view on top of another view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to add a `ProgressBar` on top of a `Button` (both are inside a `ConstraintLayout`).

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_width="280dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="75dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:text="@string/sign_in"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:textSize="22sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordEditText"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"/>

<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/progressBar"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.5"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/sign_in_button"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/sign_in_button"/>
```

But even after calling `bringToFront` on the `ProgressBar` in `onCreate`, it always stays behind the `Button`.

```
ProgressBar progressBar = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
progressBar.bringToFront();
```

Comment: this is so weird, I tried to play a bit with your layout, even inverting the chain so that the progress bar is constraint to the edit text and the button to the progress bar but the button seems to be always on top of the progress bar

Comment: Are you able to use a FrameLayout ? Give it a try, knowing that in FrameLayout, the z-index is given by the order inside the layout ( so Button 1st, Progress 2nd )

Comment: where is your passwordEditText as i checked without app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/passwordEditText" i can see progress bar on top can u provide that  passwordEditText

Answer (score 252, accepted):

Set an elevation on the `ProgressBar`; `2dp` seems to work.

```
android:elevation="2dp"
```

You could also try setting `translationZ` as suggested in the accepted answer to a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26524552/android-5-0-progressbar-cannot-be-displayed-over-a-button).

I also came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27216368/6287910) as an alternative.

Comment: But `elevation` and `translationZ` are only for API >=21, what about older APIs?

Comment: @q126y I don't think this became an issue until API 21, so older APIs should not need this. I have tried it on an emulator running API 17 and the progress bar appeared on top as expected.

Comment: @Cheticamp so How to handle this? AS is giving a warning it works only API level 21 and higher.

Comment: @Anaya See my comment above. If you don't want to see the warning, check build version at run time.

Comment: @q126y `ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(view, 5)`

Comment: `ViewCompat.setElavation(view, 20f)` helps you

Comment: @SilviaH , inside of `ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(...) SDK_VERSION checks automatically.
 if (VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
      view.setTranslationZ(translationZ);
    }

Comment: Elevation in API < 21 is defined by tag order in the XML. The view/layout at the top is at the bottom of the stack.

Comment: why 2dp? Is 1dp ok?

Comment: @hmac If it works for you, yes. `2dp` was the smallest I could get down to with the layout provided.

Answer (score 27):

We need to use android:elevation to control this.

```
android:elevation="10dp"
```

This elevation attribute only work in API level >= 21. But In below that it will behave normally. If we add Progress below the Button view it show the view which is in the bottom at the top of the other view.

Answer (score 13):

You can simply define the view which you want on top after the one which should appear below it.

With buttons, note that their elevation is governed by their stateListAnimator. The stateListAnimator of `Widget.MaterialComponents.Button` has a default elevation of `@dimen/mtrl_btn_elevation` (2dp). So if you want to show a view on top of a Button, it should have an elevation of at least 2dp.

Comment: How do you ensure that coz the xml can accidentally get rearranged

Comment: @Cristan, its better to provide a code snippet or an example. Thanks

Comment: I wonder why `ProgressBar` isn't on top of the `Button` even though `ProgressBar` is defined after `Button` in the question.

Comment: I thought this was true too but no matter where I place an imageview in the constraint layout ordering, it is always appearing behind a button

Comment: I finally figured out why this doesn't seem to work for buttons. I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 8):

In Constraint layout you should use

traslationz

higher than view that you want to below .

Answer (score 5):

Although `android:elevation="4dp"` or `traslationz` will work, but for that API level should at least 21. If for some reason you can't do that, make sure the view you want on top is mentioned after other views. For example, if I want progressBar on top of ImageView:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".ImageActivity">

<ImageView
   android:id="@+id/image_view"
   android:layout_width="0dp"
   android:layout_height="0dp"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="6:4"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<ProgressBar
   android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
   style="?android:attr/progressBarStyle"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
   app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

Using elevation is working but it has some limitations like it requires api level 21+
and also if elevation is less(in my case it was 2dp) then view become invisible while doing long click therefore you can use a trick simply **replace button with "View" or "TextView"** you can do everything with these views which can be done with buttonView

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer for Android Sutdio 3.5:

In the updated Layout Editor it's now much easier to choose which View will be in front as demonstrated in the Android Studio release notes

> .. In addition, a blue overlay now highlights the target of the constraint. This 
>   highlighting is particularly useful when attempting to constrain to a component that 
>   overlaps with another.

https://developer.android.com/studio/releases

Even easier, 
If you drag the View up (copy paste or from the Component Tree in the layout editor)  it will get lower priority (so it will be behind the other views)

Answer (score 1):

Button by default have TranslationZ set , so you have two options

1 - make progress bar TranslationZ greater than button elevation

```
ViewCompat.setTranslationZ(progressBar, 5)// to support older api <21
```

2 - make button TranslateZ to 0 so the views Appear above each other in order in your Constraint Layout , you can achieve this by Setting Style to button

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless"
```