# How do I get the imageButton in front of the buttonView in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, layout, constraints, hierarchy

Coming from Xcode, I'm really confused with Android Studio. I want to do such a simple thing as putting one view above another, but for some reason, the view I want to the front ends up in the back:
[image]

`imageButton` should be in front of `chapter1` but no matter how I arrange the hierarchy it still ends up in the back. Should I add imageButton as a `subview` to `chapter1`? Should I surround the items with a container? In Xcode, you just put one view on top of another. So much simpler, or am I missing something?

Comment: You should be able to set the `app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf` to set the top of `chapter1` to the bottom of `imageButton`. Alternatively, using the UI editor, when you highlight a component, there should be a little dot at each side that you can click+drag to any of the side of another component.

Comment: Thanks, but I think you're missing the point. I have already set the constraints as I want it to be. The problem is that imageButton is below chapter1. I want imageButton to be in front of chapter1...

Comment: the way you proposed your question did not make that clear.

Answer (score 1):

OK, found an answer now: [Android ConstraintLayout - Put one view on top of another view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44351354/android-constraintlayout-put-one-view-on-top-of-another-view)

For `imageButton` make sure that you add xml:

```
android:elevation="2dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by using [FrameLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout). In FrameLayout you can put views on top of each other with the last view under the hierarchy shown on top. 
To get ImageButton in front of Button view:

```html
        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
                
            <ImageButton
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
          />
```